# Trying to add percentages together and type conversion

Tags: javascript, for-loop, numbers, type-conversion

I have a variable which is a number. I'm trying to loop through an project and add the values from that object to my variable to get the total. The numbers are percentages and returned as string (the numbers in the object).

```
//ADD ALL SUBTASK COMPLETION % AND DIVIDE IT BY TOTAL SUBTASK COUNT
console.log(curItemPercent); //this is hardcoded as 0.8 for now
var total = curItemPercent;
var parentCompletion;

function getTotal(data){
    var index = data.length;
        for(var i = 0; i < index; i++){
            var sum = total + parseInt(data[i].percentage,10);
        }
        taskCount = index+1;
        parentCompletion = total/taskCount;

        console.log('total:' + total);
        console.log('Count: '+ taskCount);
        console.log('percent: '+parentCompletion);
}
```

I keep getting 0 or the numbers just don't add and total remains the same.

Comment: `var sum = total + parseInt(data[i].percentage,10);` isn't doing anything because you aren't keeping a cumulative sum and aren't doing anything with `sum`.  Do you mean to initialize `total = 0` at the beginning of your function and then do `total += parseInt(data[i].percentage,10);`?  Also, what is in `data[i].percentage`?  Is it an integer or a decimal string?

Comment: if `data[i].percentage` is actually a decimal, you shoudl be using `parseFloat`.  If you actually want a solution, why not give us a jsfiddle?

Comment: @jfriend00, they're decimals, I'll use parseFloat instead. And total already has a value (curItemPercent)I'm trying to add to this value using the loop.

Comment: I was able to get it working with both your suggestions. Thank you.